# How to display more than 2 tables with different total record in 1 tag table html or datatable

Tags: php, html-table, datatables, native

I'm trying to display some tables with different total of the record, but they always showing the same total of the record with some record doubled.

this is a display that i want to build :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSXPh.jpg

Comment: show us some code

Comment: i think you need to reset the `total` variable to 0 before counting the next table

Comment: its a total of record, not total the data in the record. wait ill show you my code